# overriding Alternatingrowstyle in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which uses the Alternatingrowstyle property, but I also would like to higlight each row when the user Edit the row, but using this code, it only highlights the rows that don't have the Alternatingrowstyle.

```
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;


            if (e.NewEditIndex % 2 == 0)
            {
                gv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow; 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want the Edit-Row to have yellow background, but only if it normally would have Alternatingrowstyle? If you want to apply a style on the edit-row, you only have to use the `EditRowStyle`-property, for example: `<EditRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />`

Comment: Tim: i want edit-row to have yellow background only when the user EDIT the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow & ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit))) {   
       e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow;   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of success with gridview highlighting using Matt Berseth's samples and in particular, [this extender](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/10/gridviewcontrolextender_ii_hea.html)